# How do I fix inconsistent accessibility: property type FFT_Plotter is less accessible than

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

How do I create a variable that has a global scope throughout a form? Here's what I have so far...

```
namespace FFT_Plotter
public partial class Form:form1 
{
public void chart1_DragDrop(...)
 {
     FFT myFFT = new FFT(); 
     myFFT.SomeFunction();
  }
   ...
 public void radioButton1_CheckChanged(...)
 {
  foreach( Series s in chart1.Series)
     {
      myRadix.DoesSomething  
      }
 }
 public class FormData
 {
    public FFT fft; 
  }
 public class AllFormData
 {
    List<FormData> myList 
 }
}
```

For clarification. I would like to be able to get myFFT in all of the form controls. The FFT class goes

```
  namespace FFT_Plotter
  {
    class FFT 
    {
     public int pInt
     private int prInt
     }
    ...       
  }
```

So far my research has shown that the FormData class should be set to public but I've done that and it's still giving me the same error.

> inconsistent accessibility: property type FFT_Plotter is less accessible than...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a public field of a type that is not also public.

The field;

```
public FFT fft;
```

is public, of type FFT;

```
class FFT 
{
    ...
}
```

...which is not since it's missing the public keyword.

Make the class FFT public or lower the accessibility of the field, and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that the other classes that were involved with FFT were also not declared public and that had been preventing me from declaring myFFT. It also had been confusing me greatly. Thank you for your response it was much appreciated.